# Fourier Transform on Musical Notes

Tags: fourier-transform, music-theory

I am trying to apply the Fourier transform analysis on music. So far, I am aware that the Fourier transform is essentially the breaking down of superposed sine waves, into its individual frequencies.
I am using 2 frequencies: 98Hz and 147Hz.

I am really confused as to how to make a time-domain graph and also a frequency-domain graph from the superposed graph. Also, I am not sure where the 'circular path' involving polar coordinates play a part in this transform.
Overall, I am trying to make the superposed sine graph, into a frequency-domain graph. However, I am not sure how.

Any answer is appreciated :)

Comment: So what have you tried and where you get stuck?

Comment: @mathreadler In fact, I am clueless as to where to start. My goal is to 'deconstruct' the graph to its individual frequencies. After doing so much research, I couldn't really decide on what to do. I have tried to sum up the functions myself, but I don't know what to do with it.

Comment: If you know some programming language then you can try to search for FFT libraries for your language of choice. If you don't, then some of them have built in FFT routines, like for example Gnu Octave. You will need to  load sound file somehow. I think there is built in support to open some audio formats. Then you need to check the sampling rate and THEN you can start doing some short time FFT and plot. But all of these things are mostly practical steps to get going and not so much about how to interpret the ransform result.

Comment: @mathreadler I see.. I appreciate your response. I did see many lines of codes that are used to run and perform the FFT. Actually, I am interested in doing the FFT manually by using the formulas themselves. Not quite sure how to apply them and where to start.

Comment: Why do you want to do it manually? It is like 1000 calculations involved for even just a hundred samples and for most high quality sound you need 40 000 samples per second. It would be 600000 multiplications for one second of music.

Comment: @mathreadler Im doing it manually because it is for my school assessment. I have used MATLAB to do perform the FFT and it worked. I just need a few sample calculations on the idea of how the Frequency Domain Signal graph is constructed. I have tried to use the Fourier formulas (there are many different ones.), and couldn't really figure out how to use it.